# How do I check if my current version of Joomla is running bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla, content-management-system

The Joomla I am working with at the moment is version 3.3.6

I am creating an article running bootstrap code and it seems that the grid classes are not applying. Is there a way to check if this version is running bootstrap?

Comment: As a fault finding measure, try temporarily switching to the default Protostar template to check if the classes work as ProtoStar uses Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's easy to understand, As Joomla is loading the template and most likely the template is loading Bootstrap CSS file, thus, you are able to check bootstrap.css in the source. So, easily check the source of your template in the browser and view source and looking for .css files and probably you will find bootstrap.min.css or a name similar to this. However, if you are concatenating the CSS files you may file your bootstrap source in the another file. However, you can check .css files in your source and find out what version is using.

When you find the files just look for this comments it could be n the top of the `bootstrap.css`:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
....
```

it shows you are using v3.3.7 or you may find something different.